# Curtain transistion between activities

Tags: android, android-animation

I want a transition between my splashscreen and my "home" activity.

The splashscreen consists in two images (the same image with mirror effect). The upper image translate to the top, the lower one translate to the bottom. The home is appearing behind.
It's like a curtain which is opening.

I don't find a solution to have two separate activities for this animation.
If I make only one activity, the problem is that the "home" has an actionbar whereas the splashscreen doesn't have one.

Do you see a solution?

Comment: Some search led to this, https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-porting/c75-7TMgn3A/discussion

Comment: I believe for the HomeActivity you can use a default transition animation (e.g. Fade-In) and for Splash you can do what you are doing right now.

Comment: Gaurav Arora, 
1. the problem is applying the animation (translation) to the activity does not provide a solution to apply 2 animations to 2 views in the activity...
2. Using the fade in, it will appear on all the screen, not only the middle. At the beginning of my animation in splashscreen, the middle being revealed will be empty.

Comment: Looks like I misunderstood your question. If using one activity, you can try ActionBar.hide() initially and ActionBar.show() after the splash animation is complete.

Comment: It's not very beautiful because we see the home screen without then the actionbar appears.